# Previous version of Z3 for Windows

Tags: z3

Does anyone know how I can get previous versions of z3 for Windows?

I want to try Spec# and developers recommed to use 2.15 version, so, I have checked [Older Versions](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Older%20Versions) page and when I tryed to download 2.15 version I have got error: 
"Unable to access the site

The webpage at ftp://ftp.research.microsoft.com/downloads/0a7db466-c2d7-4c51-8246-07e25900c7e7/z3-2.1.msi might be temporarily down or moved permanently to a new web address."

Comment: All of Microsoft Research was moved onto a new web server earlier this year and in that process these old downloads were not migrated. I'll have a look around, but I can't guarantee that I'll find them.

Comment: I zipped an old installation of Z3 2.15, I hope it works as a portable application: https://polybox.ethz.ch/index.php/s/r9sTrXWKm5nwzsi. I'll soon delete the uploaded file again, however, so please grab it quickly.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @MalteSchwerhoff!